# Dynamic UI - setContentView( ) or Fragment?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments

I would like to know what the best approach for creating a dynamic UI is. I have a simple chat app with a single activity where I present the user with UI that change depending on whether they're logged in or not.

Currently, I swap fragments in and out. However, I could also use `setContentView( )` instead.

Which one would be a better approach in terms of performance of the app and maintainable code?

Answer (score 1):

Both the approaches have some pros and cons.

1. Two fragment approach:

   **pros**: The code for two situations stays in separate fragments and is cleaner, easier to maintain.

   **cons**: Some performance penalty. Fragments have their own craziness. [See this for example](https://corner.squareup.com/2014/10/advocating-against-android-fragments.html)
2. setcontentView approach

   **pros**: lightweight.

   **cons** : The code that handles both the scenarios needs to be in the same activity. If you add more scenarios (e.g. logged in as a guest etc). You need to write more code to handle multiple scenarios and test them.

Comment: Ok, and which approach would make it easier to add the new lollipop activity transitions, if I were to add a second activity in the future ?

Comment: Really I'd say the cons to setContentView (particularly the complexity of needing to account for multiple states) are so high that you should never use it in any non-trivial app.

Comment: It is possible to use an MVP or some such design and cleanly separate the states at the start and work on the two independently. You could also use something like a ViewSwitcher to switch from one type of view to another. It involves more work but can be done.

Comment: @GabeSechan Single activity and [`flow`](https://github.com/square/flow) library perhaps? :) Would that make it less complex ?

Comment: @LittleChild I've never used flow.  From a quick glance, it seems to be remaking fragments.  I tend to avoid libraries like that like the plague-  they tend to make things slightly easier for newbies making a small usecase of apps, and nearly impossible to work with if your use case grows beyond that.

Comment: @GabeSechan So... what'd be your preferred approach ? :)

Comment: Just fragments.  They really aren't all that complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this site
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

If you develop an application, you should consider the followings:

1. mobile and tablet compatibility
2. Maintainable
3. Reusable

Fragment provide these functionalities but activity did not ( at least hard to implement)